# What information does dwExtraInfo hold for the PMOUSEHOOKSTRUCT?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(_In_ int nCode, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    BOOL fpassmove = FALSE;

    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
            
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE: // how do i catch a dx instead of a cursor points?


                
                PMOUSEHOOKSTRUCT me = (PMOUSEHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
                
                printf("x:%d\ny:%d\nextrainfo:%04X\n", me->pt.x,me->pt.y, me->dwExtraInfo );
                break;
        }
    }
    return(fpassmove ? 1 : CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}

int main()
{
    // Install the low-level keyboard & mouse hooks
    HHOOK hhkLowLevelMouse = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LowLevelMouseProc, 0, 0);
    // Keep this app running until we're told to stop
    MSG msg;
    while (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {    //this while loop keeps the hook
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhkLowLevelMouse);

    return(0);
}
```

I am looking at all mouse moment from a global hook, and I'm trying to find the dx and dy of the mouse event, And I was hoping to find it in "dwExtraInfo". However, I have no idea how to make sense of the data inside "dwExtraInfo".

the windows documentation is not helpful in telling me what the data in dwExtraInfo means

```
dwExtraInfo

Type: ULONG_PTR

Additional information associated with the message.
```

[image: here is an image returned by dwExtraInfo]

Comment: Your code is using a `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook. Its callback doesn't use `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT` (that is used by `WH_MOUSE` instead), it uses `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`. They both have `dwExtraInfo`, but at different offsets in memory, so you are printing out trash data due to using the wrong struct type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could not find any documentation on `dwExtraInfo` directly, but found something related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessageextrainfo:

> Return value
>
> Type: **LPARAM**
>
> The return value specifies the extra information. The meaning of the
> extra information is device specific.

One example of such device specific extra information is Pen gestures: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tablet/system-events-and-mouse-messages

> **Distinguishing Pen Input from Mouse and Touch**
>
> When your application receives a mouse message (such as
> WM_LBUTTONDOWN), it may call the GetMessageExtraInfo function to
> evaluate whether the message originated from a pen or a mouse device.
>
> The value returned from GetMessageExtraInfo needs to be mask-checked
> against 0xFFFFFF00, and then compared with 0xFF515700. The following
> definitions may make this clearer:

```cpp
#define MI_WP_SIGNATURE  0xFF515700
#define SIGNATURE_MASK   0xFFFFFF00
#define IsPenEvent(dw)   (((dw) & SIGNATURE_MASK) == MI_WP_SIGNATURE
```

> If the comparison is true, then this mouse message was generated by a
> Tablet PC pen or touch screen. In all other cases, you can assume that
> this message was generated by a mouse device.
>
> The lower 8 bits returned from GetMessageExtraInfo are variable. Of
> those bits, 7 (the lower 7, masked by 0x7F) are used to represent the
> cursor ID, zero for the mouse or a variable value for the pen ID.
> Additionally, in Windows Vista, the eighth bit, masked by 0x80, is
> used to differentiate touch input from pen input (0 = pen, 1 = touch).